# $M=\{a+b\sqrt{2}: a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ and $N=\{c+d\sqrt{3}: c,d \in \mathbb{Q}\}$. $M \cap N \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $M=\{a+b\sqrt{2}: a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ and $N=\{c+d\sqrt{3}: c,d \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.

Prove $M \cap N \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The $\in$ symbol is not appropriate for that second sentence. $\in$ only applies to elements inside sets. The symbol for set inside set is $\subseteq$. Do you mean to say "Show $M\cap N \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$" or possibly even $M \cap N = \mathbb{Q}$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in M \cap N$.

Then $x \in M$ and $x \in N$.

$x \in M$ means that $x = a + b\sqrt{2}$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Also, $x \in N$ means that $x = c + d\sqrt{3}$ for some $c, d \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Therefore, for $x \in M \cap N$, the following must be true:

$$a + b\sqrt{2} = c + d\sqrt{3}$$

for some $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Equality is satisfied in $$a + b\sqrt{2} = c + d\sqrt{3}$$

if and only if

$$b = d = 0$$

and

$$a = c.$$

Comment: And therefore $M\cap N=\mathbb{Q}$ which is presumably what he wanted to prove.

Comment: Your last sentence is surely what has to be proved here?

Comment: From the original question, I am guessing the OP wanted to prove that $M \cap N$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Yes. And the hardest part of that is proving that $a + b\sqrt{2} = c + d\sqrt{3} \implies b = d= 0$. Not that it's particularly hard $-$ see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

What we have to prove is this:

If $a+b\sqrt 2 = c+d\sqrt 3$ with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Q$, then $b = d = 0$.

$$\begin{align}
a+b\sqrt 2 & = c+d\sqrt 3 \\
(a-c)^2 & = (d\sqrt 3 - b\sqrt 2)^2 \\
& = 3d^2-2bd\sqrt 6 + 2b^2
\end{align}$$

So
$$bd \sqrt 6 = \frac12(3d^2+2b^2-(a-c)^2)$$
is rational. We know $\sqrt 6$ is irrational, so we must have $bd = 0$. Suppose $b = 0$. Then $a = c + d\sqrt 3$, so $d\sqrt 3$ is rational, hence $d = 0$. Similarly, $d = 0 \implies b = 0$.

Hence $b = d = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

*Given* $M=\mathbb{Q(\sqrt 2)}$ and $N=\mathbb{Q(\sqrt 3)}$, where $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt 2)}$ and $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt 3)}$ are the smallest field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing both ($\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt 2$ )and ($\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt 3$) respectively.

Let us consider $M\cap N$. If $x\in M\cap N,$ then $x\in M$ and $x\in N$, So

$a+b\sqrt 2=r+s\sqrt 3,$ $ a,b,r,s\in \mathbb{Q}$

$\implies a=r$ and $b=s=0$ *because b,s $\in \mathbb{Q}$. The only other way possible was $b=\sqrt 3$ and $s=\sqrt 2$, which would violate the fact that b,s $\in \mathbb{Q}$. Thus $x=a=r$ and hence $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, proving that $M\cap N \subseteq\mathbb{Q}$*. $\square$